# Problem with plugin - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this problem with a plugin in zend framework.
I've created on this route:

```
library/Mis/Plugins/Unpluginmas.php
```

in application.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Mis_"

resources.frontController.plugins.Unpluginmas = "Mis_Plugins_Unpluginmas"
```

Unpluginmas.php

```
class Mis_Plugins_Unpluginmas extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{
```

Zend Framework not find the plugin.
I appreciate if you can help me because I can't find the problem.

Comment: double check the permissions for that file , its may the reason for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, remove the underscore from your namespace prefix.  That should be automatically added.

Second, lowercase your plugin name string.

```
resources.frontController.plugins.unpluginmas = "Mis_Plugins_Unpluginmas"
```